# Add class to nav if part of url matchs the menu items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let us say i have  following main menu structure for which i need to add class active class to nav if part of url matches the menu link

for example 
`www.domain.com/en/blog/this-is-firt-blog` in this case i need to add `active` class to second item in name `/blog`

```
    <div class="wrapper">
    <ul>
<li><a href="/en/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/en/blogs/" >All Blogs</a></li>
    <li><a href="/en/videos/" >All Videos</a></li>
    <li><a href="/en/contact/" >Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aYBzRd

I use below code to match the part of url which is `/blog` but this code adds active class to all menu items

```
 $(".wrapper li a").first().removeClass("active-menu");

        var pathnameurl = window.location.pathname;

        if (pathnameurl.indexOf('/blog') != -1) {
           // alert("match");

            $(".wrapper li a").each(function (index, element) {
                $(element).addClass("active");

            });
        }
        else
        {
            alert("nomatch");
        }
```

I tried using `$(this).addClass("active");` but that also adds active class to all menu items

Comment: does the pathname always start /en/blog or /en/video or /en/contact?

Comment: It can be `/en/blog/` or `/ar/blog/` or `/es/blog` for this reason i am trying to match only `/blog` part

Comment: But can you also have paths like /en/video or /es/contact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you try something like this:

```
$('[href*=blog]').addClass('active')
```

https://codepen.io/kuzmanovic/pen/pLNJNo?editors=1111

p.s. your css also required change to work

EDIT: If you need to add slash to css selector:

```
$('[href*="/blog"]').addClass('active')
```

Comment: i tried to change it to `$('[href*=/blog]')` which breaks it.

Comment: try $('[href*="/blog"]').addClass('active')

Answer (score 3):

Use This

```
        $(".wrapper li a").removeClass("active");

        var pathnameurl = window.location.pathname; //'someurl/en/blogs/'

        $(".wrapper li a").each(function (index, element) {
              var $el = $(this);
              var href = $el.attr('href');

              if (pathnameurl.indexOf(href) >= 0)
                $el.addClass("active");

        });
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eMBNMB

Comment: here is the main thing if (pathnameurl.indexOf(href) >= 0). href is element's href attribute value

Comment: which part do you want to explain me?

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this to your code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<ul>
<li><a id="x" href="/en/">Home</a></li>
<li><a id="y" href="/en/blogs/" >All Blogs</a></li>
<li><a id="z" href="/en/videos/" >All Videos</a></li>
<li><a id="w" href="/en/contact/" >Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Then in the javaScript code try this:

```
var pathname = window.location.href;
if (pathname.indexof("/blogs") > -1){
    document.getElementById("y").classlist.add("active");
    document.getElementById("z").classlist.remove("active");
    document.getElementById("w").classlist.remove("active");
}else if(pathname.indexof("/videos") > -1){
    document.getElementById("z").classlist.add("active");
    document.getElementById("").classlist.remove("active");
    document.getElementById("w").classlist.remove("active");
}else if(pathname.indexof("/contact") > -1){
    document.getElementById("w").classlist.add("active");
    document.getElementById("y").classlist.remove("active");
    document.getElementById("z").classlist.remove("active");
}
```

if you are using word press try:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<ul>
<li><a href="/en/">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="/en/blogs/" >All Blogs</a></li>
<li><a href="/en/videos/" >All Videos</a></li>
<li><a href="/en/contact/" >Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

and your js will be:

```
var pathname = window.location.href;
if (pathname.indexof("/blogs") > -1){
    var li = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
    for(var i = 0;i<li.length;i++){
        if(li[i].innerText === "All Blogs"){
            li[i].classlist.add("active");
        }else {
            if (li[i].classlist.contain("active")){
                li[i].classlist.remove("active");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This must fix your problem obviously and Good Luck.

Comment: Not sure if this is practical as this menu is database driven and add `id` to each `li` not possible.

Comment: thanks for your comment but i meant to put the id at the "a" tag but are you using word press?

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var pathnameurl = window.location.pathname;
if (pathnameurl.indexOf('/blog') != -1) {
    $('a').each(function() {
        if($(this).attr("href") == "/en/blogs/") {
            $(this).parent().addClass("active")
        }
    }); 
}
else {
    alert("nomatch");
} 
});
```

try this

Comment: I have to match based on href not `.text()` as text can change

Comment: @Learning if you get you answer the don’t forget to accept answer

Answer (score 1):

make sure to remove all the classes from *a* tag

```
var pathnameurl = window.location.pathname;
if (pathnameurl.indexOf('/blog') != -1) {
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(".wrapper li a");
    for(var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if(elements[i].getAttribute("href").indexOf("/blog") > -1) {
            elements[i].className = "active";
        }
    }
} else {
    alert("nomatch");
}
```

or using jquery

```
$(".wrapper li a").first().removeClass("active-menu");
var pathnameurl = window.location.pathname;

if (pathnameurl.indexOf('/blog') != -1) {
    // alert("match");
    $(".wrapper li a").each(function (index, element) {
        if($(element).attr("href").indexOf("/blog") > -1)
            $(element).addClass("active");
    });
} else {
    alert("nomatch");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(".wrapper li a").first().removeClass("active-menu");

    var pathnameurl = window.location.pathname;
    $(".wrapper li a").each(function() {
        if(pathnameurl.indexOf($(this).attr("href")) != -1)

        {
            $(this).addClass("active");
        break;
        }

        else
    {
        alert("nomatch");
    }
    });
```

Comment: This won't work as the menu items have e.g. href="/en/blogs/" and the path starts "/en/blog/". But definitely the right approach.

Comment: how will i match `/blog` or `/video` or where are you matching

Answer (score 1):

This code should work for any URL starting with /xy/type where xy is a 2 letter code (e.g. /en/blog..., /es/video...). It should be easily modifiable for similar forms.

```
// get the path name
var pathnameurl = window.location.pathname;
// extract the path type - assumes path is of the form /xy/type/...
var pathtype = pathnameurl.replace(/^\/..\/([a-z]+).*$/, '$1');
// now set the corresponding menu item active
$('[href*=' + pathtype + ']').addClass('active');
```